# calling javascript from eclipse for PhoneGap

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, code-injection

I am trying to load a website using Phonegap on Android with the following code:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setBooleanProperty("loadInWebView", true);
    super.loadUrl("http://arriva.com.mt");

}
```

How would I execute a local javascript file on the webview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having problems with this but managed to resolve it myself in the end. In your Activity you have 
**`super.loadUrl("javascript:yourFunction()");`** within your code -- make sure you have a window scoped function to fire **`window.yourFunction = function()`**. As you're using PhoneGap I would assume that javascript is already enabled in the webview. If not, you will need to enable that too, you might find my post useful for finding out about that.

[Calling javascript functions in a webview from activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916624/calling-javascript-functions-in-a-webview-from-activity-class)

HTH

Comment: This worked for me, but after it works the app returns an error saying "The connection to the server was unsuccessful".  So even though the javascript executes, it still tries to make a request using that line as a url.  Not sure if there is a way around this or not.

Comment: @Caimen Do you get this happening in a normal android setup or only with phonegap implemented? 

As a side note, in my own experience I started out using phonegap but quickly realised it wasn't doing a lot for me(I only required a couple of phone functions exposed, connection & location). So I binned that idea and went pure droid code to keep it light and just as simple.

Comment: Yes I have had better experience just writing pure Droid code myself.  However we are also developing for IOS and possibly other OSs.  I am also on PhoneGap 1.0 and since we have been developing 1.2 has come out.  I did get this working eventually using the super.loadUrlTimeoutValue = 2000000000; before calling the url for the javascript.  This is of course an extreme hack and am looking for a different ways of achieving the same thing.